# Python webcam record giving lower fps than desired

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video, python-multithreading, webcam-capture

I am using opencv(cv2) in python to record videos(only video required) from multiple webcams simultaneously. Though they are not synchronized they record at a constant framerate. The problems are

1. They record at 4fps when resolution is set to 1080p, while desired is 30fps. The cameras I am using support this. While previewing though the framerate is 30fps which leads me to believe I may be doing some thing wrong while recording. I am using threading as in imutils library to get the videos as suggested in [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/) blog post.
2. Is there anyway to synchronize the different camera outputs(videos).

PC specs:

- Intel i5 7thgen,
- 8gb ddr3 ram,
- SSD harddrive.

The webcams I'm using are Genius 32200312100 WideCam F100 USB 2.0 WebCam.

I do not think these are a limitation as I've been monitoring the CPU and memory usage while recording.

Any help is appreciated and if any further information is required please feel free to ask.

I'm open to using any encodings that will not compromise the quality of the picture.

## Edit: I'm posting the code below.

```
 class VideoRecorder():

    #Function that runs once when the VideoRecorder class is called.
    def __init__(self,cam_id = 0):

        #Initialize the camera and set its properties
        self.cam_id = cam_id
        self.framerate = 30
        self.video_height = 720
        self.video_width = 1280
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_id)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,self.video_height)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,self.video_width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,self.framerate)

        # Grab a initial frame, It is to warm up the camera.
        # This frame will not be used
        temp1, temp2 = self.cap.read()

        #Set the place where the file is to be stored
        storage_path = "{Output_folder}"
        file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y_%H%M%S")
        file_name = "cam_" + str(self.cam_id) + "_" + file_name + ".avi"
        self.file = os.path.join(storage_path,file_name)

        #Initialize a videowriter object to save the recorded frames to a file
        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(self.file,self.fourcc,self.framerate,
                                   (self.video_width,self.video_height))


    def record(self, timer = 10):

        #Start a timer for the recording to see how long the recording should be
        self.start_time = time.time()
        #Start a frame counter to calculate the framerate at the end
        self.frame_count = 0

        #Run an loop for given time to get frames from camera and store them
        while(self.cap.isOpened()):
            tora1 = time.time()
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            print("Time for reading the frame",time.time()-tora1)
    
            if ret == True:
                tora2 = time.time()
                self.out.write(frame)
                print("Time for write",tora2-time.time())
                self.frame_count += 1
            else:
                break

            current_time = time.time()
            self.elapsed_time = current_time - self.start_time
            if(self.elapsed_time > timer):
                self.stop()
                break
            
    #Start the recording in a thread
    def start(self, timer):
        video_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.record, args = (timer,))
        #video_thread.daemon = True
        video_thread.start()

        
    #Print the fps and release all the objects
    def stop(self):
        print("Frame count: %d"%self.frame_count)
        self.fps = self.frame_count/self.elapsed_time
        print(self.elapsed_time)
        print("fps: %f"%self.fps)
        self.out.release()
        self.cap.release()
        print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Giving which arguments to pass to the script form command line ans
    #getting them in a args structure
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-t", "--runtime", type = int, default = 10,
                    help = "TIme for which the videorecoder runs")
    ap.add_argument("-id", "--cam_id", type=int, default= 0,
        help="give camera id")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    
    required_time = args["runtime"]

    video_thread = []

    for i in range(args["cam_id"]+1):
        t = VideoRecorder(i)
        video_thread.append(t)
        t.start(required_time)
```

Comment: which encoder do you want to use?

Comment: First of all, show us you code. If it's something in you code that create this issue, we cannot help unless viewing the code.